# Excel VBA programming range selection questions

Tags: vba, excel

NEED HELP DOING THIS PLEASE:

1. Opens an Input box and prompts the user to choose a worksheet number from 1 to
2. Stores the value the user entered in a variable of type integer named Index.
   You may assume the user will always enter a valid input (i.e. 1, 2 or 3). The
   program will give run time error if the user enters text for example- but you do
   not need to write code to handle this case.
3. Uses the index number entered by the user and the Worksheets( ) collection object
   to activate the selected worksheet.
4. Find the number of items in the list in column A (starting in cell A1) and store it
   in a variable named L1; find the number of items in the list in column B (starting
   in cell B1) and store it in a variable named L2.
5. Use an If statement to determine what string to store in a variable named
   Answer:
   “ List 1 is longer” if the number of items in column A is larger.
   "List 2 is longer" if the number of items in column B is larger, and
   "Same length" otherwise.
6. Open a message box showing Answer.

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Comment: Which part co you want help with? What kind of help do you need?

Comment: You are asking far too much in one go. Drop steps 2 to 6 and concentrate on step 1. A VBA program may access worksheets by numbers but the user does not know those numbers. One approach would be to have a listbox populated with the worksheet names. Another approach would be to require the user to confirm the required worksheet was active when the macro was started. Research coding a macro that addresses step 1.  If you run into difficulties, post the faulty code and explain what is wrong. Once that macro is working, research step 2.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, the assignment says they should prompt for the index.

Comment: @DougGlancy. I agree step 1 says the user enters a number but is that a reasonable design?  If the workbook has up to about five worksheets, the user can easily count along the tabs.  With more worksheets, it will be come increasingly difficult for the user to get the number correct.  Perhaps a number is OK but the OP needs to think about each step carefully if the result is to be usable.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, you're right, definitely not a good design. It's a beginning homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

```
Sub HomeworkForNmHomie13()
Dim Response, Index, L1, L2, Answer
Do
    Response = InputBox("Enter a number from 1 to " & Worksheets.Count)
    If Response = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Your teacher said don't do error handling, but that's for failures.
    On Error Resume Next
    Index = Int(Response)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Index > Worksheets.Count Or Index < 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Your entry was invalid. Please enter a number between 1 and " & Worksheets.Count)
    End If
Loop While Index > Worksheets.Count Or Index < 1
Sheets(Index).Activate
L1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming an "item" includes blank cells
L2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Just grab the last row with data
'Use 2 IIF Statements to check the length using one line of code and look smart as hell
Answer = IIf(L1 > L2, "List 1 is longer", IIf(L2 > L1, "List 2 is Longer", "Same length"))
MsgBox (Answer)
End Sub
```

If you would prefer to "impress" your teacher by meeting the minimum requirements:

```
Sub LazyHomeworkForNmHomie13()
Index = Int(InputBox("Enter a number from 1 to " & Worksheets.Count))
Sheets(Index).Activate
L1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
L2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Answer = IIf(L1 > L2, "List 1 is longer", IIf(L2 > L1, "List 2 is Longer", "Same length"))
MsgBox (Answer)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to assume this all works and upvote just for the comments :-)

Comment: thank ya. this helped. i used it to compare to my partner's code actually haha. thanks though.